# Syncfusion Calendar doesn't select datas

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, syncfusion, sfcalendar

I want to use SfCalendar from Syncfusion's pack with multiselect mode for WP8.1 project, but it doesn't work.

I can see the calendar. If I tap to any date, it selects, but `SelectedDates` has 0 elements, `SelectionChanged` event reports `RemovedItems = 1` and this item is null. Also I can't select multiple items: if I tap to other date, it selects, but previous date deselecting.

```
<input:SfCalendar SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedDates="{Binding TestDates, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionChanged="SfCalendar_OnSelectionChanged"/>
```